# Interface members signature parameters

Tags: c#, interface

I have been learning about Interfaces and my question is:
For example I have a `Car` class named: `Car` that implements an interface named: `ICar`

```
   public class Car: ICar
```

Both `Car` and `ICar` have a `Save` method:

```
  public bool Save(Car car)
    {some save logic}
```

Should the `Save` method, pass in `Car` or `ICar`, which is better practice, or does it not matter?  I was thinking `ICar`, because then if this interface is inherited by another class it will still work.

Appreciate any guidance, thanks.

Comment: Is the `Save` method a part of `ICar` interface? Why pass another instance of `ICar` then?

Comment: @orhtej2 Good point. I have removed ICar as it is not needed because I already have the current instance. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it in this way: if `ICar` expected a `Car` as a parameter, `ICar` would be depending explicitly on `Car`, while the *decoupling* is what's wanted when you use interfaces.

If `ICar` depends on `Car`:

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Save(Car car);
}

public class Car : ICar
{
    public void Save(Car car) { }
}

public class Van : ICar
{
    // Here Van needs to have a Car object, why should it?
    public void Save(Car car) { }
}
```

If `Car` were deprecated (for example, deemed too generic), you'd need to refactor your entire code.

Instead, if `ICar` depends on `ICar`:

```
public interface ICar
{
    void Save(ICar car);
}

public class Car : ICar
{
    public void Save(ICar car) { }
}

public class Van : ICar
{
    public void Save(ICar car) { }
}
```

Here, it really doesn't matter at all if `Car` exists or not, you are not *coupled* to its implementation.

However, since `ICar`, when implemented, would already be an `ICar`, you don't need to pass it as parameter.

Consider:

```
public interface ICar
{
    // Will save myself
    void Save();
}
```

Versus:

```
public interface ICar
{
    // Will save some ICar
    void Save(ICar car);
}
```

Comment: There is a compile error. 
public interface ICar{void Save(ICar car);}
public class Car : ICar{public void Save(Car car) { }}

Comment: @selami Was distracted, fixed.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Perfectly explained and exactly what I was looking for, thanks.